# d3 v4 and angular v4 histogram syntax

Tags: d3.js, angular2-directives

I'm building a very simple angular control for a d3 histogram.

I've looked at a number of tutorials online, and they all seem to be suggesting a particular syntax for the construction of the bins of the histogram:

```
  let datagenerator = d3.histogram<number>()
  .domain(d => x.domain())
  .thresholds(x.ticks(20));

  let bins = datagenerator(this.data);
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
 ERROR in src/app/d3/histogram/histogram.component.ts (45,25): 
 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

UPDATE: After trying the suggestions below, I'm making progress but now getting this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/d3/histogram/histogram.component.ts (48,15): Argument of type '(d: number[]) => number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(values: number[]) => [number, number]'.
  Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]'.

ERROR in src/app/d3/histogram/histogram.component.ts (54,15): Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(number | { valueOf(): number; })[]'.
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'.

ERROR in src/app/d3/histogram/histogram.component.ts (54,48): Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Here is the full source:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, 
ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'histogram',
  templateUrl: './histogram.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./histogram.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HistogramComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer:ElementRef;
  @Input() private histogramdata:Array<number>;

  private margin:any = {top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20};
  private chart:any;
  private svg:any;
  private width;
  private height;
  private data;

  constructor() { }

  createChart() {
    let element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
    this.width = element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
      .attr('width', element.offsetWidth)
      .attr('height', element.offsetHeight);

    // chart plot area
    this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`);
  }

  updateChart() {

    let formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");
    //this.data = this.histogramdata;
    this.data = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4];


    let x = d3.scaleLinear<number>()
      .rangeRound([0, this.width]);

    let datagenerator = d3.histogram<number, number>()
      .domain(d => x.domain())
      .thresholds(x.ticks(20));

    let bins = datagenerator(this.data);

    let y = d3.scaleLinear<number>()
      .domain([0, d3.max(bins, d => { return d.length; })])
      .range([this.height, 0]);

    let bar = this.chart.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(bins)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", d => {
        return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")";
      });

    let barWidth = x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0) - 1;

    bar.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 1)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .attr("height", d =>  { return this.height - y(d.length); });

    let textLoc = (x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0)) / 2;

    bar.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("x", textLoc)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(d => { return formatCount(d.length); });

    this.chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I understand that we have to add some type decorators to the call for typescript compatibility, but what I don't understand is why the error suggests that the histogram function should take a parameter.  All of the examples I've seen have no parameter.

Thanks for taking a look.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/blob/master/src/d3-array/index.d.ts#L345) and [tests](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/blob/master/tests/d3-array/d3-array-test.ts#L457), the signature is:

```
d3.histogram<number, number>()
```

for an array of numbers.

or:

```
d3.histogram<MixedObject, number | Date>()
```

where "Mixed Object" is a custom type match to your data and you are binning by number or date.

To help further, update your question with a sample of your data...

**EDITS**

Again, take a look at the source.  It's pretty easy to understand. The first parameter is the type in the array you are going to call the histogram function with.  It is used, for instance in the the `value` function, as in:

```
.value(( d: number, i: number ) => {
  return d;
})
```

The second type is the type used in setting the two parts to the `domain` and the type in the array specified as thresholds.  It is also used in the return object as the type of the `x0` and `x1` properties.

All that said, I just did a simple test in Angular2/Typescript with:

```
    let dataGenerator = d3.histogram<number, number>()
        .thresholds([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1]);

    let data = d3.range(100).map(() => {
        return Math.random();
    });

    console.log(dataGenerator(data));
```

And it both builds and run.

To help any further, provide a complete set of code that re-produces your problem.

**EDITS 2**

The error is actually here:

```
let datagenerator = d3.histogram<number, number>()
  .domain(d => x.domain()) //<-- ERROR
  .thresholds(x.ticks(20));
```

`x.domain()` returns `number[]`, while `histogram<number, number().domain(` is expecting `[number, number]`.

I'd sort it out like this:

```
let dom : number[] = x.domain();
let datagenerator = d3.histogram<number, number>()
  .domain([ dom[0], dom[1] ])
  .thresholds(x.ticks(20));
```

Comment: Hmmm - still a little confused.  I'm passing an array of numbers to the histogram - where does the other parameter come from.  When I make this change in my code I get the following error:

    `ERROR in src/app/d3/histogram/histogram.component.ts (46,15): 
    Argument of type '(d: number[]) => number[]' is not assignable to  
    parameter of type '(values: number[]) => [number, number]'.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
       Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]'.`

Comment: @jb44, see edits above to response to your comment.  From your error, it looks like you aren't passing an array of numbers, but rather an array of array of numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I'm still having trouble understanding how i'm passing an array of an array of numbers.  I included the source above, hard-coded the values, and still get the same error.  Its quite likely I'm making a bonehead oversight so I appreciate you bearing with me on this.

Comment: @jb44, ahh, I got it the error is in the `.domain` call.  `x.domain()` is returning `number[]`, while `histogram.domain(` is expecting `[number, number]`.  This should work: `d3.histogram<number, number>().domain([x.domain()[0], x.domain()[1]])`